# How to convert a List<string> to an IEnumerable<ServiceReference.datatable> C# Silverlight WCF RIA Services LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, silverlight

ive been working on trying to convert a list into a IEnumerable<>, passing in my Service Reference with my table in my database. i needed to convert the IEnumerable to a list of strings in the beginning, so that i could use the Sort() function, but now im trying to convert it back to a IEnumerable so i can use it as a Itemsource for my combobox. Any ideas how to do this?

im using Silverlight 5 and WCF RIA Services, using LINQ to SQL, and using the C# language.

code is below that i have so far, but nothing i have found online has been able to convert back to a IEnumerable.

ServiceReference1.LoginInfo is my table in my database.

```
         IEnumerable<ServiceReference1.LoginInfo> list = e.Result as IEnumerable<ServiceReference1.LoginInfo>;

        string comboname;

        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {

             comboname = list.ElementAt(i).UserName;
             items.Add(comboname);
             items.Sort();

        }

        //This is where i need something to convert the list<string> items to the IEnumerable<ServiceReference1.LoginInfo> list


         //set the itemsource      

        RegisterPanel_CarrierComboBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

the main reason im trying to turn this list of strings into a ienumerable again is because i need to be able to set it to my itemsource, to make my combobox work correctly. once this is all set ill be able to work on the next problem of why my combobox wont clear when i switch to another stackpanel.

any and all answers will be helpful. thank you

Comment: A `List<string>` is already `IEnumerable`. Not really sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: well what im trying to do is, i have this combobox set up on a panel that loads all the Carriers that we have in our database, when you click on a register button. it will bring up the register panel that we created, and it will load all the carriers names into the combobox. that works perfectly fine, the problem is however, if i click on our Login Hyperlink, which will disable the Register Panel and bring up our Login Page Panel, im trying to make the application Clear the information that is in the combobox. Ill put the rest in another reply because i running out of characters for this reply

Comment: like for example if the person clicks on a carrier name, but then decides to click the login hyperlink instead of filling out the rest of the form. if i try that and leave a carrier name selected and then click the hyperlink, the whole program crashes. ive tried using SelectedItem = -1 and tried using .Clear() but nothing is working. not sure if that gives you the information to understand what im getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your code you just want to sort your list of LoginInfo by username.
Correct?

```
        IEnumerable<LoginInfo> list = ...
        list = list.OrderBy(t => t.username).ToList();
```

Comment: that works thank you. i  didnt know that there was a orderby command. thank you for this.